# Python Strings with Specific WIdth

Tags: python, string, formatting, python-2.4

I have been having a bit of trouble looking up a good explanation on how to do this so pointing me to the right direction would be helpful for the following problem.

I need to have a header printed out in a pretty format along with data, unfortunately what happened 
is shown below.

```
DeviceName   KB used   KB quota   KB hard limit   grace   
/media/Stuff        58384   5242880   0   none
```

In order to do this I built a list for the header.

```
HEADER=['DeviceName', 'KB USED', . . .]
```

and the same thing with the other entries that I need to print out.
In order to print it out the above I did something like this

```
print "".join('%s'.rjust(5) %i for i in HEADER)
```

So this obviously does not work because the rjust just pads spaces to the right of string. Is there a way to print a string such that it takes up exactly a certain width and if the string isn't long enough to fit the width, then just pad it with spaces?

P.S. I am limited to python 2.4 which means I can't use format from python 2.7.

Comment: Close. You need to run `rjust()` on the string after the fact. `str(i).rjust(5)` or as has been pointed out `"%5s" % i`

Answer (score 3):

You could use `'%*s'`:

```
HEADER = "DeviceName   |KB used|KB quota|KB hard limit| grace".split('|')
data = ["/media/Stuff", 58384, 5242880, 0, None]
print '|'.join(HEADER)
print '|'.join("%*s" % (width, val) for width, val in zip(map(len,HEADER), data))
```

#### Output

```
DeviceName   |KB used|KB quota|KB hard limit| grace
 /media/Stuff|  58384| 5242880|            0|  None
```

Answer (score 2):

You want it the other way around.
How about like this:

```
>>> "%-5s" % 'sss'
'sss  '
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 '%s'.rjust(5)
```

puts the spaces in, assuming that the literal `%s` is your string. You're going to be substituting that with another string of unknown length, so you can't justify until after the substitution.

However, you don't want to explicitly `.rjust()` everything yourself, because that functionality is built into the substitution engine. Just put the field width between the `%` and the `s`.

You could build up the format string dynamically by measuring the lengths of strings in the header. Use `%%` to produce a literal `%` sign when formatting; thus, `'%%%ds' % 10` turns into `'%10s'`, which will produce a field width of 10.

Thus, something like:

```
format_string = ' '.join('%%%ds' % len(h) for h in HEADER)
print ' '.join(HEADER)
for entry in data: print format_string % entry
```

Comment: you could [use `'%*s'` instead of `'%%%ds'`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7985009/python-strings-with-specific-width/7985253#7985253).

Answer (score 0):

Format the string with a precision:

```
print ' '.join("%5.5s" % s for s in HEADER)
```

Or, slice the `rjust` result:

```
print ' '.join(s.rjust(5)[:5] for s in HEADER)
```